# Spring Boot @ModelAttribute encoding bug

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm facing an issue in production, and I don't understand if it's a bug or a feature of Spring.

I tried to create the following endpoint which create a resource. It receives a file and some structured data at it follows:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}) 
public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> create( @ModelAttribute @Valid RequestDto dto ) { ... }

@Getter @Setter 
public class RequestDto { MultipartFile file; String name; }
```

Important: No encoding configurations are made through app.properties
The strange things happens when you try to send a request with name containing characters with accents (ex: Romanian ones ăâț). For example Ă is decoded to Ä�.

I don't want explicitly a solution but rather the logic behind @ModelAttribute or any clue how to fix it, because switching to @RequestBody works fine with any type of character. Why these 2 are using different deserialisers or configurations ?